How does every vector state on a $C^*$-algebra extend to a normal state on its enveloping von Neumann algebra?
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\pi_u$ its universal representation. Consider $M=\pi_u(A)''$. Let $\phi$ be a state on $A$. Then it is a vector state on $\pi_u(A)$ via GNS, associated to a vector say $v$. Now how does $\phi$ extend to a normal state on $M$? It will be helpful if you provide the formula.

My work:
Let $x\in M$. Since $M$ is the weak-closure of $A$, there exists a net $\{x_i\}_i$ in $A$ such that $x_i\xrightarrow{weak}x$.
Define a state $\rho$ on $M$ as
\begin{equation*}
 \rho(x)=\lim_{i}\langle x_iv,v\rangle_{H_\phi}:=\langle xv,v\rangle
\end{equation*}
(Why can we take the limit out of the inner product? Essentially, why does the weak limit and inner product commute?)
To see this $\rho$ preserves suprema, see that for any sequences $\{\xi_n\}\subset H_\phi$ with $\sum_n\langle \xi_n,\xi_n\rangle=1$, $\rho$ is of the form
\begin{equation*}
 x\mapsto \sum_n\langle x\xi_n,\xi_n\rangle
\end{equation*}
(But I still don't see how we can take supremum out of the inner product and the sum.)
Perhaps I am missing something about how weak-closure works. This is also part of a greater attempt at understanding why $A^{**}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $M$.

Also see Confusion about the ability to extend a state on a C*-algebra to a normal state on a von Neumann algebra

Do you know the definition of weak limits? Because taking limits out of inner products is literally the definition of weak limits. (And suprema of increasing nets are weak - in fact, even strong - limits.)

@DavidGao Thanks! If you write this as an answer with the definition of weak limits and why supremum is a weak limit, I will accept it.
